# Open a image in a new form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a image showing in

```
picShowPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(textbox1.Text)
```

At the moment the image is showing on the main screen what I want is when a user selects a image from the database, it then open up in a new window?

how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that by "selects a image from the database" does *not* mean that you're (de)serializing BLOBs and just want the code to make the image display in a new window.  I will further assume that you have a second form created in your project called "Form2" with an image viewer called "picImageViewerOnForm2".

`var newImage = Image.FromFile(textbox1.Text);`
`var newForm = new Form2();`

`newForm.picImageViewerOnForm2.Image = newImage;`
`newForm.Show();`

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Form in Designer and pick a **PictureBox** in it. And create a special method for example

```
public void SetPicture(Image image)
```

which will set image to PictureBox.

On selecting picture call:

```
YourForm form = new YourForm();
form.SetPicture(Image.FromFile(textbox1.Text));
form.ShowDialog();
```

Or you can dynamically create new form:

```
Form form = new Form();

PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(textbox1.Text);
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: It loads up a new form but no picture is there.

Comment: Can you add code of a new created Form and code of it's creating and showing.

Comment: I have just copied directly from this example and when i click the button a new form opens with nothing inside.

Answer (score 2):

Add Form to application and put PictureBox on it, let's say that ID of PictureBox is "pictureBox1", then create public proterty on that form to access picutre box, like this :

```
public partial class ShowPictureForm : Form
{
  public PictureBox ImagePictureBox { get { return this.pictureBox1; } }

  public ShowPictureForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

then show that new form like this :

```
ShowPictureForm spf = new ShowPictureForm();
spf.ImagePictureBox.Image.FromFile(textbox1.Text)
spf.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Says inaccessible due to protection level

Comment: I am getting this error when trying other examples, do I need to change some settings?

Comment: did you add picturebox on form ?

Comment: Found out why, went into the designer code and changed it to public

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Windows Form to your project, named "ShowImageWindow".
Add a picturebox to the window, and the following code:

```
public Image ImageToShow { get; set; }


public ShowImageWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ShowImageWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = ImageToShow;
}
```

Then create and show the window as follows:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(textBox1.Text);
ShowImageWindow frm = new ShowImageWindow();
frm.ImageToShow = img;
frm.ShowDialog();
frm.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Form (new type derived from System.Windows.Forms.Form) that accept image path as constructor.

Say new form is ImageForm. Create PictureBox inside this form.

in the function ShowImageWindow (or similar in main form), call like following

```
ImageForm imageForm = new ImageForm(textbox1.Text)  
imageForm.ShowDialog()
```

In the ctor of ImageForm, set the Image into picturebox control inside ImageForm

```
 public ImageForm(String imagePath)
 {
   pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new form with just picture box in it.
2. Then when forming that forms object pass image as parameter(of course you have to create a parameterised constructor of your form) and pass that image in a global image variable.
3. In Form_Load set that global image variable as your image controls image.